# How to skip a line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code:

```
  <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>
       Reasons for proposals selected and not selected
    </nobr>
  </h3>
```

this is my image:
[image]

but my text is too large, and I want to insert `<br>` to skipping a line, like this:
[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need jquery and don't do it directly in the HTML?

Comment: I dont have access to the HTML

Comment: this is a form in Sharepoint, and this is the HTML in the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```js
$('nobr').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('selected and', 'selected<br />and');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>
       Reasons for proposals selected and not selected
    </nobr>
  </h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var e = "Reasons for proposals selected<br/> and not selected";
    $(".ms-standardheader nobr").html(e);
    });
  </script>
```